# No module named 'scipy.io.matlab'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

import sklearn.preprocessing returns the following error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8931cbb9678f> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import sklearn.preprocessing

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py in <module>
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
      7 
      8 from .data import Binarizer

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py in <module>
      3 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
      4 from ..utils import check_array
----> 5 from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
      6 from ..externals.six import string_types
      7 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py in <module>
     19 
     20 import scipy as sp
---> 21 import scipy.io
     22 from functools import wraps
     23 from operator import itemgetter

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\io\__init__.py in <module>
     95 
     96 # matfile read and write
---> 97 from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat, byteordercodes
     98 
     99 # netCDF file support

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.io.matlab'
```

I use Windows. The following packages are already installed in Python 3.7.3:
scipy 1.1.0
numpy 1.16.2
scikit-learn 0.20.3

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which os are you using, and what is your sklearn version. Can you try updating sklearn

Comment: sklearn version is the newest. numpy and scipy seem to not the newest version but are the newest available version on anaconda.

Comment: how do you install the libraries

Comment: @Jeril@ They come with and are updated by anaconda.

Comment: I do use windows, but some of the scientific python libraries have issues with windows. So for windows, i install python libraries from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: Jeril@, it works

Comment: Glad it helped..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment from @Jeril above, my issue has been resolved. It was because Scipy was not from the most recent version.

Here are the steps:
1. Download package(s) from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Please write some warnings in the Intro section.
2. If needed, copy+paste the downloaded file to Python directory. In my machine, it is located in C:\Python\Python36.
3. Open command prompt then cd to the directory where the downloaded file is saved.
4. `pip install packagefilename.whl`. Before, make sure that pip is updated.